# JToolBar spanning half of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, text-editor, jtoolbar

I am creating a text editor similar to gedit. In toolbar, i have used 10 buttons with icons. I am using a `JFrame` with `BorderLayout`. Toolbar is placed at north. But the problem is that the buttons are becoming too big and toolbar is covering almost half of the frame. All the icons are of size 512x512px. I tried resizing the icons but it didnt work. It works properly if the icons of the images are removed.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

class RSP extends WindowAdapter implements ActionListener, CaretListener
{
private JFrame f;
private JMenuBar mb;
private JMenu m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, m16;
private JMenuItem m11, m12, m13, m14, m15, m17, m18, m21, m22, m23, m24, m25, m26, m27, m28, m31, m32, m33, m41, m42, m51, m52, m53, m61, m62, m71, m72, m161, m162, m163;
private JButton b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10;
private JToolBar tb;
private JTabbedPane tp;
private JLabel l;
private JTextArea[] ta;
private int caretPos, lineNum, columnNum;

public RSP()
{
    f=new JFrame("RSPEditor");
    mb=new JMenuBar();
    CreateMenuBar();
    tb=new JToolBar();
    tb.setFloatable(false);
    CreateToolbar();
    tp=new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP,JTabbedPane.SCROLL_TAB_LAYOUT);
    l=new JLabel("",JLabel.TRAILING);
    ta=new JTextArea[10];
    f.setSize(800,550);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setJMenuBar(mb);
    f.add(tb,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    f.add(tp,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    f.add(l,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.addWindowListener(this);
}

public void CreateToolbar()
{
    tb.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,10,5,5));
    tb.setSize(f.getWidth(),20);
    b1=new JButton("New",new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("new.png")));
    b2=new JButton("Open",new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("open.png")));
    b3=new JButton("Save",new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("save.png")));
    b4=new JButton("Undo",new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("undo.png")));
    b5=new JButton("Redo",new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("redo.png")));
    b6=new JButton("Cut",new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("cut.png")));
    b7=new JButton("Copy",new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("copy.png")));
    b8=new JButton("Paste",new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("paste.png")));
    b9=new JButton("Find",new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("find.png")));
    b10=new JButton("Replace",new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("replace.png")));

    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);
    b4.addActionListener(this);
    b5.addActionListener(this);
    b6.addActionListener(this);
    b7.addActionListener(this);
    b8.addActionListener(this);
    b9.addActionListener(this);
    b10.addActionListener(this);

    tb.add(b1);
    tb.add(b2);
    tb.add(b3);
    tb.add(b4);
    tb.add(b5);
    tb.add(b6);
    tb.add(b7);
    tb.add(b8);
    tb.add(b9);
    tb.add(b10);
}

public void CreateMenuBar()
{
    m1=new JMenu("File");
    m2=new JMenu("Edit");
    m3=new JMenu("Search");
    m4=new JMenu("Execute");
    m5=new JMenu("Tools");
    m6=new JMenu("Documents");
    m7=new JMenu("Help");

    mb.add(m1);
    mb.add(m2);
    mb.add(m3);
    mb.add(m4);
    mb.add(m5);
    mb.add(m6);
    mb.add(m7);

    m11=new JMenuItem("New");
    m12=new JMenuItem("Open");
    m13=new JMenuItem("Save");
    m14=new JMenuItem("Save As");
    m15=new JMenuItem("Print");
    m16=new JMenu("Recent Files");
    m161=new JMenuItem("A");
    m162=new JMenuItem("B");
    m163=new JMenuItem("C");
    m16.add(m161);
    m16.add(m162);
    m16.add(m163);
    m17=new JMenuItem("Close");
    m18=new JMenuItem("Quit");

    m21=new JMenuItem("Undo");
    m22=new JMenuItem("Redo");
    m23=new JMenuItem("Cut");
    m24=new JMenuItem("Cop[y");
    m25=new JMenuItem("Paste");
    m26=new JMenuItem("Delete");
    m27=new JMenuItem("Select All");
    m28=new JMenuItem("Insert Date and Time");

    m31=new JMenuItem("Find");
    m32=new JMenuItem("Replace");
    m33=new JMenuItem("Goto Line");

    m41=new JMenuItem("Compile");
    m42=new JMenuItem("Run");

    m51=new JMenuItem("Indent");
    m52=new JMenuItem("Spell Check");
    m53=new JMenuItem("Full Screen");

    m61=new JMenuItem("Save All");
    m62=new JMenuItem("Close All");

    m71=new JMenuItem("How To");
    m72=new JMenuItem("About");

    m1.add(m11);
    m1.add(m12);
    m1.addSeparator();
    m1.add(m13);
    m1.add(m14);
    m1.addSeparator();
    m1.add(m15);
    m1.addSeparator();
    m1.add(m16);
    m1.addSeparator();
    m1.add(m17);
    m1.add(m18);

    m2.add(m21);
    m2.add(m22);
    m2.addSeparator();
    m2.add(m23);
    m2.add(m24);
    m2.add(m25);
    m2.add(m26);
    m2.addSeparator();
    m2.add(m27);
    m2.addSeparator();
    m2.add(m28);

    m3.add(m31);
    m3.add(m32);
    m3.addSeparator();
    m3.add(m33);

    m4.add(m41);
    m4.add(m42);

    m5.add(m51);
    m5.add(m52);
    m5.addSeparator();
    m5.add(m53);

    m6.add(m61);
    m6.add(m62);

    m7.add(m71);
    m7.add(m72);

    m11.addActionListener(this);
    m11.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_N, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    m12.addActionListener(this);
    m12.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_O, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    m13.addActionListener(this);
    m13.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    m14.addActionListener(this);
    m14.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK | ActionEvent.SHIFT_MASK));
    m15.addActionListener(this);
    m15.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_P, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    m161.addActionListener(this);
    m162.addActionListener(this);
    m163.addActionListener(this);
    m17.addActionListener(this);
    m17.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    m18.addActionListener(this);
    m18.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));

    m21.addActionListener(this);
    m21.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Z, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    m22.addActionListener(this);
    m23.addActionListener(this);
    m23.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_X, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    m24.addActionListener(this);
    m24.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    m25.addActionListener(this);
    m25.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    m26.addActionListener(this);
    m27.addActionListener(this);
    m27.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_A, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    m28.addActionListener(this);

    m31.addActionListener(this);
    m31.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    m32.addActionListener(this);
    m32.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_H, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    m33.addActionListener(this);
    m33.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_I, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));

    m41.addActionListener(this);
    m42.addActionListener(this);
    m42.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F9, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK));

    m51.addActionListener(this);
    m52.addActionListener(this);
    m53.addActionListener(this);
    m61.addActionListener(this);
    m62.addActionListener(this);
    m71.addActionListener(this);
    m72.addActionListener(this);
}

public void createNewTab()
{
    ta[tp.getTabCount()]=new JTextArea();
    ta[tp.getTabCount()].addCaretListener(this);
    ta[tp.getTabCount()].setFont(new Font("Ariel",Font.PLAIN,20));
    tp.addTab("New File",new JScrollPane(ta[tp.getTabCount()]));
}

public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)    //prompt for save
{
}


public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource().equals(b1) || e.getSource().equals(m11))
        createNewTab();
    else if(e.getSource().equals(b2) || e.getSource().equals(m12));
        //fileOpen();
    else if(e.getSource().equals(b3) || e.getSource().equals(m13));
        //save;
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m14));
        //saveas
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m15));
        //print
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m161));
        //recent1
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m162));
        //recent2
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m163));
        //recent3
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m17));
        //close
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m18));
        //quit
    else if(e.getSource().equals(b4) || e.getSource().equals(m21));
        //undo
    else if(e.getSource().equals(b5) || e.getSource().equals(m22));
        //redo
    else if(e.getSource().equals(b6) || e.getSource().equals(m23));
        //cut
    else if(e.getSource().equals(b7) || e.getSource().equals(m24));
        //copy
    else if(e.getSource().equals(b8) || e.getSource().equals(m25));
        //paste
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m16));
        //delete
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m17));
        //select all
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m18));
        //insert d&t
    else if(e.getSource().equals(b9) || e.getSource().equals(m31));
        //find
    else if(e.getSource().equals(b10) || e.getSource().equals(m32));
        //replace
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m33));
        //goto
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m41));
        //compile
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m42));
        //run
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m51));
        //indent
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m52));
        //spell chk
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m53));
        //fullscreen
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m61));
        //saveall
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m62));
        //closeall
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m71));
        //howto
    else if(e.getSource().equals(m72));
        //about
}

public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) 
{ 
    JTextArea editArea=(JTextArea)e.getSource();
    lineNum=1;
    columnNum=1;
    try
    {
        caretPos=editArea.getCaretPosition();
        lineNum=editArea.getLineOfOffset(caretPos);
        columnNum=caretPos-editArea.getLineStartOffset(lineNum);
        lineNum++;
        l.setText("L "+lineNum+", C "+columnNum+"     ");;
    }
    catch(Exception ex) { }
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    new RSP();
}
}
```

Comment: What you have so far ?

Comment: I have a menubar, a label working as status bar at south, and jtabbedpane at center. The tabbedpane has jscrollpane as each tab, which contains a jtextarea.

Comment: post your code to get better solutions

Comment: So your screen is what, at least 5120px wide?  No most systems, buttons tend to be 16-32 or maybe 48px...

Comment: Please post your code and maybe the link to an image showing your problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer i tried reducing the size of images but it still didnt work.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**scale the Images the following way and it should work**

```
new JButton("New", new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("new.png")).getImage().getScaledInstance(50, 50, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
```

**I am scaling to 50X50 you can use any proper size that suit your application**

Comment: it is showing an error RSP.java:46: error: incompatible types: Image cannot be converted to Icon b1=new JButton("New",new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("new.png")).getImage()).getScaledInstance(50, 50, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);

Comment: @SanketB I have updated the answer hope it will work, it is working for me :)

Comment: @SanketB I am happy to help you, you can also vote up my answer :)

Comment: @Muhammad: He needs more reputation to up-vote answers. Why instantiate `ImageIcon` twice?

Comment: once to get the image and scale it 2nd to pass it to JButton as it need ImageIcon and a string